# What is the best way to deploy multiple Angular SSR apps to Digital Ocean droplet?

Tags: node.js, angular, digital-ocean, server-side-rendering, angular-universal

I am trying to deploy an Angular SSR (Server Side Rendering) app that contains multiple projects/websites to a Digital Ocean droplet. My question is, when I deploy should each project/website have its own nodejs server running or can I just start one nodejs server and deploy just the dist/project folder? So basically one nodejs server is running all the projects (on their own ports of course).

Essentially it would be nice to have just one nodejs server running and I can sftp my dist/project for any updates.

Answer (score 2):

I also had trouble performing this task, but using DigitalOcean Apps you can deploy in just a few steps in few minutes.
You just have to modify your package.json file and push on Git then you're done!

> Next step:

1.In your `package.json` file, replace:

These two lines

```
"start": "ng serve",
"build": "ng build",
```

With

```
"start": "npm run serve:ssr",
"build": "npm run build:ssr",
```

2.Push on Git
3. At the DigitalOcean Apps, choose the type of **Web Service** application in step 2, and update this:

> Build Command

```
npm run build:ssr
```

> Run Command

```
npm run serve:ssr
```

Then continue with the process, the application will be automatically deployed!

Comment: Did you maybe managed with angular 17 in nx workspace? Stuck on this for 2 days now.

Answer (score 0):

So I found out you can just push the dist folder, the key is to use reverse proxy that points to your server.js file for each project. I followed this tutorial:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-a-node-js-application-for-production-on-ubuntu-20-04